# Method of sorted in python

Tags: python-3.x

The same code, run several times, but get the different results. Why the following results is not sorted?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post the code in the question itself - don't post a link to an image on an external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your results into a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#mapping-types-dict) – a data structure that does not guarantee any order of keys/values. It seems you're aware of that, judging by your call to [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted).

However, that function doesn't work as you presume: rather than modifying the list (or any iterable, in general), it *returns a new one*. Documentation linked above states:

> Return a new sorted list from the items in iterable.

And since result of this function isn't assigned to any variable, it perishes. Alternately, result can be used directly as a collection to iterate over in a `for` loop, like this:

```
for key in sorted(scores):
    print(scores[key] + ' had ' + key)
```

Comment: There is no need to call .keys